# Woocommerce attribute label as an image

Tags: woocommerce, product

I am using `woocommerce` and on shop product page I am showing `attribute-label: attribute-value.

For example like: `Tire: Snow`

Instead is there a way to show attribute-label as an image?

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'isa_woocommerce_all_pa', 25);
function isa_woocommerce_all_pa(){
    global $product;

    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    if ( ! $attributes ) return;

    $out = '<ul class="custom-attributes">';

    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {

        if ( $attribute->get_variation() ) continue; // skip variations

        if ( $attribute->is_taxonomy() ) {
            $taxonomy = $attribute->get_name();
            $taxo_obj = $attribute->get_taxonomy_object();
            $name = $taxo_obj->name;
            $label = $taxo_obj->label;

            $out .= '<li class="' . esc_attr( $taxonomy ) . '">';

            ## ATTRIBUTE IMAGE ##
            // For a child theme use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead.
            $out .= '<img class="attribute-image" src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/attributes/'.$name.'.jpg" alt="Attribute '.$label.'"/> ';
            $out .= '<span class="attribute-values">';

            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'names') );

            foreach ( $terms as $term_name )
                $term_names['name'] = $term_name;

            $out .= implode(', ', $term_names);
            $out .= '</span></li>';

        } else {
            $value_string = implode( ', ', $attribute->get_options() );
            $out .= '<li class="' . sanitize_title($taxonomy) . ' ' . sanitize_title( $value_string ) . '">';
            $out .= '<span class="attribute-label">' . $taxonomy . ': </span> ';
            $out .= '<span class="attribute-value">' . esc_html( $value_string ) . '</span></li>';
        }
    }
    $out .= '</ul>';

    echo $out;
}
```

Comment: Please add to your question the code you are using to show `attribute-label: attribute-value` on shop page…

Comment: ok so i took the code from one post you made 1 month ago, did everything as you described, but the image doesn't appear.

Comment: Ok found the guilty in the code… Updated. Try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since WooCommerce 3.2+ there is a change in WC_Product_Attribute object syntax. I have corrected the code and it should work for you too… This will be shown on single product pages (but not on shop page):

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'isa_woocommerce_all_pa', 25);
function isa_woocommerce_all_pa(){
    global $product;

    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    if ( ! $attributes ) return;

    $out = '<ul class="custom-attributes">';

    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {

        if ( $attribute->get_variation() ) continue; // skip variations

        if ( $attribute->is_taxonomy() ) {
            $taxonomy = $attribute->get_name();
            $taxo_obj = $attribute->get_taxonomy_object();
            $name = $taxo_obj->attribute_name; // <== Corrected
            $label = $taxo_obj->attribute_label; // <== Corrected

            $out .= '<li class="' . esc_attr( $taxonomy ) . '">';

            ## ATTRIBUTE IMAGE ##
            // For a child theme use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead.
            $out .= '<img class="attribute-image" src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/attributes/'.$name.'.jpg" alt="Attribute '.$label.'"/> ';
            $out .= '<span class="attribute-values">';

            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'names') );

            foreach ( $terms as $term_name )
                $term_names['name'] = $term_name;

            $out .= implode(', ', $term_names);
            $out .= '</span></li>';

        } else {
            $value_string = implode( ', ', $attribute->get_options() );
            $out .= '<li class="' . sanitize_title($taxonomy) . ' ' . sanitize_title( $value_string ) . '">';
            $out .= '<span class="attribute-label">' . $taxonomy . ': </span> ';
            $out .= '<span class="attribute-value">' . esc_html( $value_string ) . '</span></li>';
        }
    }
    $out .= '</ul>';

    echo $out;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

As Product attributes dont have images, you should create a in your active theme a folder images (if it doesn't exist) and inside a subfolder attributes.

For each product attribute, you will have to add an image inside this subfolder attributes, which name will be the name of your attribute (the slug). For example for "`Color`" attribute you will have to add an image named `color.jpg`.